# ESP8266 not connecting to Arduino IDE

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, esp8266, wifi, iot

I've been trying to connect the ESP8266 Wifi module to my Arduino Leonardo and program the wifi module from it (using Arduino IDE). However, I'm not able to get the connection established! I tried many tutorials but I simply may be missing out on something. In the schematics, I tried to respect the colors of the wires exiting out on the module.

In Arduino IDE I've installed "Generics ESP8266 Module" and set the port to the port connected to Arduino Leonardo. It says "[not connected]" after reseting the Leonardo, but then I select the Arduino Leonardo port again in Tools and it disappears. However, I get no response from writing the command "AT+RST" into the serial monitor, or any other AT command for that matter.

When I try to upload the Blink code, they are not connected (last image).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foQ4ic.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your RX/Tx connections are wrong. The Tx of the Arduino needs to connect to the Rx of the ESP, and the Rx of the Arduino connects to the Tx of the ESP.

Comment: @LordTeddy I thought of that, but the tutorials I've seen always say to connect Rx-Rx and Tx-Tx. For example: https://www.donskytech.com/program-esp8266-esp-01-with-arduino/ or https://www.electronicshub.org/esp8266-arduino-interface/

Comment: @ludicrous Did you try swapping them?

Comment: @EdinFifić I did, but still didn't work (writing "AT" into serial monitor didn't produce "OK" and uploading of code failed)

Comment: Ahh, that's my mistake, that is the right way round for what you're doing

Comment: Have you been pressing the reset button on the ESP (not the Leonardo). Are you sure there's nothing programmed on the Leo that would try to use the serial port?

Comment: @LordTeddy I uploaded an empty code before connecting the ESP. When I press the reset on the breadboard the ESP led blinks but nothing changes. I starting to wonder if its something to do with being a Leonardo and not Uno(?)

Comment: It looks like you need to wire the nReset line of the Leo to 5V. This will hold it in reset so the uController does nothing. Both those examples use an Uno, but they remove the actual chip so it doesn't interfere

Comment: @LordTeddy that makes sense. I now plugged the 5V into Arduino's RESET, but I'm still not getting a response when I type "AT" into the Serial Monitor (even after resetting), nor able to upload the code into the ESP, but that seems like a step forward.

Comment: When are you resetting the ESP? During the programming cycle when the dots/underscores appear? You wont get any response from it untill you program it

Comment: @LordTeddy but the thing is I'm not able to program it because when I try to upload it it has no connection, as in the last picture

Answer (score 0):

You use the approach for an Uno where the RX/TX pin of the board are RX and TX pins of the USB chip so you can use the USB chip of the Uno as an USB to TTL Serial adapter.

On Leonardo there is no USB chip. The Atmega32u4 has native USB. The RX and TX of Leonardo are Serial1 so you have to bridge Serial (USB) to Serial1 with the SerialPassthrough basic example uploaded into Leonardo.

Wire RX to TX between Leonardo and the esp8266. Set the baud-rate in the SerialPassthrough sketch to 115200 baud.

The 3.3 V pin of Leonardo may not be able to provide enough current to run WiFi on the esp8266.